# Get information from active running Powershell Instance in Vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, powershell

I am currently working on a small software for my company. It's about investigating processes during runtime. Now to my question respectively the problem.

Is it possible to inspect/analyze a Powershell instance that was started independently from my tool which commands should be executed BEFORE they are really executed? Or are the commands interpreted 1to1 at runtime?

I hope you can help me here with whether my undertaking is possible at all.

Many thanks and a nice day

Comment: Your question is unclear. In particular, can you explain what "which commands should be executed BEFORE they are really executed" means?

Comment: I mean when the process spawns after a double click on the ps1 file, is it possible to retrieve the commands that will be executed BEFORE the are interpreted/executet by powershell. I dont mean to read the file. I mean like investigate the process / dump informations from memory or something like that, before the commands really run.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777). Please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: There is a simple question. Is it possible to realize in VB.NET? No XY Metashit here!!!!